# $L^p$ boundedness of a function

Tags: integration, operator-theory

In a Banach space $X$, let $T:X\rightarrow X$ be a bounded operator and $f:[0,a]\rightarrow X$ a measurable function. Assume that $Tof\in L^p([0,a],X)$, is $f\in L^p([0,a],X)$?
Thank you.

Comment: do you mean  $ T : L^p([0,a],X)  \to L^p([0,a],X) $ ?

Comment: No, $T$ acts on $X$. Hence writing $Tf \in  L^p([0,a],X)$ means that the function $h(\cdot)=Tf(\cdot)$ belongs to $L^p([0,a],X)$.

Comment: So by $Tf$ you mean $Tof$ right?

Comment: Yes, it can be regarded as a composition.

Comment: BTW what do you mean by $ L^p([0,a],X) $ ?!

Comment: The space $L^p([0,a],X)$ is like Lebesgue space but for vector valued functions, i.e. the space of all integrable functions in Bochner sense. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space for more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following gives you a category of examples where $T \neq 0$

Let $T : X \to X$ be a bounded linear map which map in which $Ker (T) \neq \{0\}$

Now consider any function $g:[0,\frac{1}{2}a]\rightarrow Ker(T)$ such that  $g \notin L^p ([0,\frac{1}{2}a], Ker(T))$ (take $g$ so that $\int \|g\|_{X} = + \infty$.)

Now define $f:[0,a]\rightarrow X$ with $f=g$ on  $[0,\frac{1}{2}a]$,   and $f=0$ on  $(\frac{1}{2}a, a].$ Observe that $f \notin L^p([0,a], X)$

Therefore you can check that $Tof (t) = 0 \quad  \forall t \in [0,a]$ which shows $Tf\in L^p([0,a],X)$.

This gives you a hint about a necessary condition such that $f\in L^p([0,a],X).$

Comment: Thanks for your constructive example, effectively,  $Ker(T)\neq 0$ is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily:

- If $Tg=0$ for all $g$, $f$ can be anything measurable.
- If $Tg=g(a)$ is evaluation to a constant, $f$ can again be anything measurable.
- For a more specific example, $T: f(x) \mapsto xf(x) $ is bounded (by $a$), and if 
  $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^{-1/p} & x>0 \\ 0&  x=0\end{cases},$$ 
  then 
  $$Tf = \begin{cases} 1 & x>0 \\ 0&  x=0\end{cases},$$
  so $Tf \in L^p$ but $f \notin L^p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any condition on $T$ such that $f$ belongs to Lp?

Comment: You probably need something like [coercivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function#Norm-coercive_mappings).

Comment: In your first example, $T =0$ . What is $T$ in your second example ?

Comment: It replaces $g(x)$ by the constant function given by $g$'s value at a particular point $a$.

Comment: But in your examples, you considered the operator $T$ as an operator acting on $L^p([0,a],X)$ not on $X$ as i assumed. So is your answer valid in this case?

Comment: That's exactly why I asked you,   shouldn't  $T : L^p([0,a],X)  \to L^p([0,a],X)$ @Amaynou   

I got confused, but first example is valid though, not two others

Comment: Yes, for $T$ acting on $L^p([0,a],X)$ the answer is given by @Chappers. If $T$ acts on $X$ I don't know.

Comment: The first example still works in the $X \to X$ case. One can come up with more complicated examples using projections, I expect.

Comment: I really don't know what $L^p([0,a],X)$ means?